# How to get the Block Irreversible status?

Tags: nodeos, blocks, irreversible, irreversible-state

I can get the irreversible status of the transaction because transaction information has both `last_irreversible_block` and `block_num` to know the status. But how to get this information for Block?
Getting Block information returns:

```
{
  "timestamp": "2021-01-28T17:58:59.500",
  "producer": "inith",
  "confirmed": 0,
  "previous": "02e1c78787ff4d4ce6124831b936bb4ef6015e470868a535f1c6e04f3afed8a1",
  "transaction_mroot": "0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
  "action_mroot": "1bf9d17b5a951cbb6d0a8324e4039744db4137df498abd53046ea26fa74d73c9",
  "schedule_version": 1,
  "new_producers": null,
  "producer_signature": "SIG_K1_JxFfxGA1wZx9LCVjbrBb5nxTuJai7RUSiwRXyY866fYvZZyRtdmQFn9KJCqVHFAiYEsJpDb6dhTmHNDwipJm4rDiyhEmGa",
  "transactions": [],
  "id": "02e1c7888a92206573ae38d00e09366c7ba7bc54cd8b7996506f7d2a619c43ba",
  "block_num": 48351112,
  "ref_block_prefix": 3493375603
}
```

It has `block_num` but not `last_irreversible_block`. And What is `confirmed`? Is it related to irreversible status?

Comment: have a look at https://github.com/liquidapps-io/eosio-push-guarantee/blob/main/src/index.ts

Comment: Any idea about what is ```confirmed``` ?

Comment: https://developers.eos.io/manuals/eos/latest/nodeos/plugins/chain_api_plugin/api-reference/index#operation/get_block confirmed - 
number of prior blocks confirmed by this block producer in current schedule

Comment: bp schedule is round robin, 6s per producer, 12 blocks, so perhaps the confirmed is other blocks confirmed within that window, though I've never looked into this field before.

Comment: Okay @Nat, I will go through it. Thank you

Comment: I'm @natpd on telegram, let me know if you have issues

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use /v1/chain/get_info to know the last_irreversible_block_num